# Quill.js how to use setText with basic formatting

Tags: javascript, quill

I'm having trouble understanding how I would populate the Quill editor with some basic HTML text using plain js.

I'm passing text with basic formatting (just bold, italic, underline and header tags) so there aren't any advanced RTF features to worry about.

So for example: My javascript might be something like

```
var postContent = "<h2>My short post</h2><p>This is a <strong>really, really</strong> short post.</p>";

quill.setText(postContent, "api");
```

I thought I'd be able to use **quill.setText(postContent, "api")** but that seems to display the HTML tags instead of rendering the formatted text.

Do I actually need to parse the code into a blot? Seems like there must be a way to get Quill to render that basic HTML, as it seems to work if I paste  simple formatted text directly into Quill.

One thing I've tried is simply doing:

```
quill.root.innerHTML = postContent;
```

Which seems to work visibly, but I'm worried that I'm now doing something a little hacky and I might not actually be using Quill as intended. Shouldn't there be a way to accomplish this via the Quill API?

Any insight?  Thanks.

Comment: 1. Are you sure about `Q` is not small `q`. 
2. add `\n` add the end.
3. You can read this small [document](https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#settext)

Comment: Changed lowerCase "q'. Thanks UU.  Adding the newline doesn't seem to get the HTML to render though. (Was that the intended result?)

Comment: this is what is stated on the official documents "Sets contents of editor with given text, returing a Delta representing the change. Note Quill documents must end with a newline so one will be added for you if omitted. Source may be "user", "api", or "silent". Calls where the source is "user" when the editor is disabled are ignored."

Comment: Right, but "given" text (postContent) in the above example isn't plaintext, which is how it's rendering. I'm asking about the basic formatting. The only thing that seems to preserve the formatting is actually setting the quill.root.innerHTML directly... which seems hacky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is unsafe deprecated function dangerouslyPasteHTML:
https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/clipboard/#dangerouslypastehtml

It's better to use setContents or updateContents with Delata of ops with attributes:
https://quilljs.com/docs/api/#updatecontents